# response.body is null even after passing data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a notification from one app to another using Firebase Cloud Messaging. I have spent a couple of days now trying to figure out what the problem is. I have passed a notification body to specific token id. When i debug my app it says 'mService is not available' and when i run the app it throws a NullPointerException.
The content i am trying to send is ok as per my analysis.

I have checked the interface IFCMService,FCMClient and the Main class, they all seem to be ok but i still don't understand why i am getting a null response.body. I have also checked my server key and it is well. I have seen a few similar questions but none have been able to specify why this issue may occur. Kindly anyone, i would really appreciate your help.
Below is my IFCMService code

```
    public interface IFCMService {
@Headers({"Authorization:key=" + "<YOUR SERVER KEY>",
        "Content-Type:application/json"})
@POST("fcm/send")
Call<FCMResponse> sendMessage(@Body Sender body);
   }
```

FCMClient class

```
    public class FCMClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseURL)
{
    if (retrofit == null){

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

    }
    return retrofit;


}
    }
```

This is the declaration and specific code where i get the error. The 'mService.sendMessage(content)' section is where the NullPointerException is thrown.

```
        protected void sendRequestDriver(String driverId){
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"send driver",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.token_tbl);


    tokens.orderByKey().equalTo(driverId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Token token = postsnapshot.getValue(Token.class);

                String json_lat_lng = new Gson().toJson(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()));


                Notification notification = new Notification("X", json_lat_lng); 


                Sender content = new Sender(notification,token.getToken());



                mService.sendMessage(content)
                        .enqueue(new Callback<FCMResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<FCMResponse> call, Response<FCMResponse> response) {


                                if (response.body().success == 1)
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Request sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<FCMResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                                Log.e("ERROR",t.getMessage());

                            }
                        });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one please:

```
public interface IFCMService {
@Headers({"Content-Type:application/json",
          "Authorization:key=" + "<YOUR SERVER KEY>"
})
@POST("fcm/send")
Call<FCMResponse> sendMessage(@Body Sender body);
   }
```